# TouchListener is overriding a ClickListener

Tags: java, android

I have a RelativeLayout with a SlidingDrawer.  I am using the drawer as a menu.  When you click on an item in the drawer, it adds a ImageView to the RelativeLayout.  I'd like to be able to move the ImageView around.

I am using a ClickListener for each menu item in the SlidingDrawer.  This part works great.  For the objects I add to the RelativeView, I set a TouchListener.  For the ImageView being added, I set a TouchListener.  But after one ImageView is added, the menu items don't work anymore.  The TouchListener takes over control and the ClickListener gets bypassed.

Here's the code:

```
    OnClickListener navClickListener;  //This is set for each menu item
    OnTouchListener objectTouchListener  //This is set for each new ImageView

    navClickListener = new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            performClickAction(v);
        }
    };

    objectTouchListener = new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
            performTouchAction(v, event);
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Why is the TouchListener overriding the ClickListener and how do I get around that?

Comment: Can you put the bit of code to attach the listeners to the views?

Comment: Do both the `RelativeView` and `ImageView` touch listeners return false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the that OnTouch wasn't overriding the OnClick at all.  The Image was being added to the Layout with the MATCH_PARENT set for both axis and was taking up the whole screen.  Since the image was a circle, it didn't appear to be taking up all of the screen and the buttons on the side were clearly visible, but the ImageView was apparently occupying the whole screen.

thanks to those that responded!